# check video playback on Mobile App

Tags: automated-testing, appium, robotframework, mobile-applications, mobile-testing

I am working on a hybrid mobile app (React native) automated testing project using robot framework and Appium, i'm looking for a way to test videos streaming.

Is there a way to test if the video playback in UI works as expected ?

Comment: What is expected? What do you want to test? I suppose if a human sees the video or tries the playback function, they can say if it's a plesant experience or not. Perhaps that's one test. You can think up more.

Comment: i want to test that the whole videos are playing and not stuck.